# Pandas — set values using partial slicing on MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have this bit of code, which produces the following empty DataFrame:

```
>>> first = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> second = ['baz', 'can']
>>> third = ['ok', 'ko']
>>> colours = ['blue', 'yellow', 'green']

>>> idx = pd.IndexSlice
>>> ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(np.array([i for i in itertools.product(first, second, third)]).transpose().tolist(),
                                   names=('first', 'second', 'third'))
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=ix, columns=colours).sort_index()
>>> print(df1)

                   blue yellow green
first second third                  
bar   baz    ko     NaN    NaN   NaN
             ok     NaN    NaN   NaN
      can    ko     NaN    NaN   NaN
             ok     NaN    NaN   NaN
foo   baz    ko     NaN    NaN   NaN
             ok     NaN    NaN   NaN
      can    ko     NaN    NaN   NaN
             ok     NaN    NaN   NaN
```

What I intend to do, is populate this MultiIndex-based empty DataFrame from another DataFrame that is given and which is column-based, like the following (columns truncated for clarity):

```
     baz_ok_blue  baz_ko_blue  can_ok_blue  can_ko_blue  baz_ok_yellow
foo    -1.385111    -1.014812    -1.419643     1.540341       0.663933
bar     0.445372    -0.226087     0.450982    -1.114169       0.896522
```

So far I've been trying this way:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
for s in second:
    for t in third:
        for c in colours:
            column_name = '{s}_{t}_{c}'.format(s=s, c=c, t=t)
            values = df2[column_name]
            df1.loc[idx[:, s, t], c] = values
```

In each iteration, the `values` Series is correctly determined, however Pandas doesn't match the index of `values` with the first level of df1's MultiIndex. As a result, all df1 values stay `NaN`, because Pandas is trying to match a MultiIndex with a single Index. Is there a way out of this?

Basically, to give a higher-level perspective, I'm simply trying to rearrange df2 (string-columns based) into the form of df1 (MultiIndex based).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `MultiIndex` first by [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), then reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and last [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
print (df)
          baz                 can                 baz
           ok        ko        ok        ko        ok
         blue      blue      blue      blue    yellow
foo -1.385111 -1.014812 -1.419643  1.540341  0.663933
bar  0.445372 -0.226087  0.450982 -1.114169  0.896522

df = df.stack([0,1]).reindex(index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)
print (df)
                        blue    yellow  green
first second third                           
bar   baz    ko    -0.226087       NaN    NaN
             ok     0.445372  0.896522    NaN
      can    ko    -1.114169       NaN    NaN
             ok     0.450982       NaN    NaN
foo   baz    ko    -1.014812       NaN    NaN
             ok    -1.385111  0.663933    NaN
      can    ko     1.540341       NaN    NaN
             ok    -1.419643       NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, brilliant. However, it seems that some values are lost in the last stage (they're still there after stacking, but disappear after reindexing — most end up being `NaN`)

Comment: Is possible simulate it?

Comment: It may be caused by the fact that in reality, columns `second` and `color` can have the same label — I'm gonna try changing this

Comment: Yep — still same problem, even after making sure column labels can't be the same — all data is still there after `stack()` and most values end up being `NaN` after `reindex()` — strange

Comment: Is no some difference in labels if check `df.index` (after stack) and `df1.index` ?

Comment: oops, I think levels `print (df.index.levels)` and `print (df1.index.levels)`

Comment: My mistake — I was inadvertently inverting `second` and `color` in df2's column names

Comment: Works perfectly now! Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @Jivan - supeeer, nice day!